# Conditional auto-wiring in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-profiles

I have a spring boot application for which I want to create separate profiles for external and embedded tomcat. How can I check in my method which profile is active so that I can run the code based on particular profile.
I came up with some code as shown below.

```
if("${spring.active.profile}".contains("external_tomcat_profile")) {
            //do something; 
 }else{
            //another thing;
        }
```

The above code does not work. How can I implement this functionality? or Is there and better way of doing this?
And I am using two profiles one "test" for testing and another either embedded or external tomcat, so is it correct to use this condition

```
if("${spring.active.profile}".contains("external_tomcat_profile"))
```

Comment: Use different beans which are available per profile which contain the different code. Use the `@Profile` to have them included. You can then execute the code in an `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Environment` bean for that

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

public void aMethod() {
   String[] activeProfiles = env.getActiveProfiles();
}
```